# Network adapter is unavailable on guest machine since import from VMWare to VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox

I've recently migrated my virtual machine from VMWare to VirtualBox due to performance issues (which seem that are solved in VirtualBox).

My guest OS is Windows 8.1 and my host is Windows 10.

However, I can't get the network adapter to show up in the guest machine at all. I've tried the following:

1. Reinstall the guest additions.
2. Reinstall the network adapter via Device Manager. Unfortunately *Intel/PRO1000 MT Desktop Adapter* didn't show up on the list.
3. Change between NAT and Bridged Adapter connection modes.

[Here's a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3Tua.png) Something definitely is wrong but I have no idea what it is.

Nothing has worked. What am I supposed to do?

Answer (score 1):

I found a fix! Set the network mode to NAT, then under Advanced, set Adapter Type to *Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)* and installed the appropriate driver via Device Manager and it works.

Answer (score 0):

For windows server, I set Adapter type to MT / Server (NAT). When I started windows, it detected the driver and worked properly.